# Unable to delete file using fs.removeSync()

Tags: node.js, angular

I am using angular 6. I want to delete multiple files from backend folder for that, I am using `fs.removeSync()` but it gives below exception for me.
can someone help me?

> "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: fs.removeSync is not a
>   function "

**My Code:**

```
fs.removeSync('/NodeWorkspace/uploads/output/*.csv');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) removeSync function not exist. For delete file use `unlinkSync` function like this:

`fs.unlinkSync(path)`

But I don't think that work for multiple files, you can use [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) package:

```
var glob = require("glob")

// options is optional
glob("/NodeWorkspace/uploads/output/*.csv", options, function (er, files) {
    for (const file of files) {
         fs.unlinkSync(file);
    }
})
```

***Note:*** Remember for delete directory use `fs.rmdir();`

Answer (score 4):

`fs.removeSync(path)` is a function of [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) library which is a wrapper over `fs` provided by nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `fs.unlinkSync(path)`.